# Making a modal image with a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

For a class assignment, I have to make a gallery of images which i will be using on my final website. when a image is clicked, an enlarged version of that image will be displayed on the page as a modal image. However, the image that is been clicked on has to be a "thumbnail image", which is at a way smaller resolution (480x270) that the enlarged one, which is at 1920x1080.

This is my HTML code (I used anchors for the enlarged image and img src for thumbnail image):

```
<a class="myImages" id="myImg" href="screenshots/image1.jpg" target="_blank">
   <img src="screenshots/thumbnails/image1-480.jpg" alt="description" style="width: 100%">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70%;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImages');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  img.onclick = function() {

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.href;
  }
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Most of the code is from W3Schools, I just modified it a little so that it works with a gallery of 20+ images.

However, because there is an anchor tag around the img, if i don't include the `target="_blank"`, when the image is clicked on, it will just open up the enlarged image on the same page and not the modal. If I include the `target="_blank"`, the enlarged image will open in a new tab, but the modal will open up on the original page too.
The result I need is a combination of the two described above, the modal needs to open up without the image opening in a new tab as well.

Is there something I am doing wrong? and how would I fix it?

Comment: event.preventDefault in your click handler and event.stopPropagation

Comment: Sorry if this sounds noobish, I only started doing web design course a month ago, so there's a lot which i am still learning. Could please explain how I would do that/where I put that? :)

Comment: looks like you have an answer with what I am taking about below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `e.preventDefault()` in `onclick` function should do the job.

And don't forget to bind the `event` to the function

```
img.onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.href;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Could you explain to me what the "e" is in the function please? does it just stand for "current event"? Just so I know what to do if this happens again in the future :)

Comment: Yes, It's current event you're handling.
Usually `event` is bind to the first argument by default if you use common HTML event attribute eg. onclick.
I'm not good at explaination. If you want to find more, you can look further in [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my questions and explaining stuff to me! I really appreciate it ^^